# Не видит метод addContentPane

Tags: java

package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame frame = new Frame("The Game");


    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JLabel qustLabel = new JLabel("Question: ");
    JLabel ansLabel = new JLabel("Answer: ");

    JTextArea question = new JTextArea();
    JTextArea answer = new JTextArea();

    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.NORTH, panel);
    
    frame.setSize(400, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Мы тоже его не видим, что дальше?

Comment: Вы имели ввиду getContentPane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У класса [Frame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html) нет метода getContentPane(). Возможно вы имели ввиду класс [JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)

Исправьте

```java
Frame frame = new Frame("The Game");
```

на

```java
JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Game");
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло.